# Why is Serilog LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration action not implemented

Tags: configuration, serilog

I am getting:

```
ArgumentException: Configuration for Action<Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration> is not implemented.
```

I've got a configuration something like this, [loosely based on the sample](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/tree/dev/sample/Sample):

```
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
        "LevelSwitches": { "$controlSwitch": "Verbose" },
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "MyApp.Something.Tricky": "Verbose"
            }
        },
        "WriteTo:Async": {
            "Name": "Async",
            "Args": {
                "configure": [
                    {
                        "Name": "File",
                        "Args": {
                            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({Application}/{MachineName}/{ThreadId}/{ThreadName}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Enrich": [
            "FromLogContext",
            "WithThreadId",
            {
                "Name": "AtLevel",
                "Args": {
                    "enrichFromLevel": "Error",
                    "configureEnricher": [ "WithThreadName" ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "When",
                "Args": {
                    "expression": "Application = 'MySample.Service'",
                    "configureEnricher": [ "WithMachineName" ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "MySample.Service"
        },
        "Destructure": [
            {
                "Name": "With",
                "Args": { "policy": "MySample.Logging.CustomPolicy, MySample.Service" }
            },
            {
                "Name": "ToMaximumDepth",
                "Args": { "maximumDestructuringDepth": 3 }
            },
            {
                "Name": "ToMaximumStringLength",
                "Args": { "maximumStringLength": 10 }
            },
            {
                "Name": "ToMaximumCollectionCount",
                "Args": { "maximumCollectionCount": 5 }
            }
        ],
        "Filter": [
            {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                    "expression": "Application = 'MySample.Service'"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "With",
                "Args": {
                    "filter": "MySample.Logging.CustomFilter, MySample.Service"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And a `Logging` support class like this:

```
static class Logging
{
    internal static ILogger Logger { get; } = BuildConfiguration().CreateLogger();

    private static DateTime Now { get; } = DateTime.Now;

    private static string GetLogFilePath(string subsystem = null)
    {
        var fileNameWithoutExtenskion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.GetFileNameWithoutExtension();

        var nowTimeStamp = Now.ToString("s").Replace(":", "_");

        const string dotlog = ".log";

        var logFileName = IsNullOrEmpty(subsystem)
            ? Join("-", $"{fileNameWithoutExtenskion}", $"{nowTimeStamp}{dotlog}")
            : Join("-", $"{fileNameWithoutExtenskion}", subsystem, $"{nowTimeStamp}{dotlog}");

        const string myComp = "My Comp";

        return CommonApplicationData.GetFolderPath().Combine(myComp, logFileName);
    }

    private static ILogger CreateLogger(this IConfigurationRoot root)
    {
        const string errors = nameof(errors);

        return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(root)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(GetLogFilePath()) /*, monitor: new MonitorConfiguration()*/)
            .WriteTo.Conditional(
                e => new[] { LogEventLevel.Error, LogEventLevel.Fatal }.Contains(e.Level)
                    , a => a.File(GetLogFilePath(errors))
            )
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    private static IConfigurationRoot BuildConfiguration()
    {
        var execAssyLocation = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

        var jsonFilePath = Path.Combine(execAssyLocation.GetDirectoryName(), "appsettings.json");

        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(path: jsonFilePath, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
    }

    private static string Combine(this string path, params string[] paths) => Path.Combine(
        paths.Any() ? new string[] { path }.Concat(paths).ToArray() : new string[] { path }
    );

    private static string GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this string path) => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);

    private static string GetDirectoryName(this string path) => Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    private static string GetFolderPath(this Environment.SpecialFolder folder) => Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
}
```

As far as I know, I've got all the requisite packages referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was an issue of my needing to reference a dev release of the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` package. Then it suddenly started to work.

Comment: The dev release is not required any longer, but for anyone with this issue, make sure to update your nuget packages.